# Is there a way to remove ugly text appearing above my matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two cells that use matplotlibs plot function however the top cell has this unaesthetic text above it (eg - ([<matplotlib.axis.YTick at 0x7fe2b81d24d0> , [Text(0, 1, '1') ) while the bottom cell does not. Is there a way to remove this text to make it more aesthetically pleasing?

I attempted to remove the labels completely however the text "(0.0, 20.0)" remained.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Initialises first three elements of array sequance and sets accumalator a to start at 0
sequance = [1,1,1] 
a = 0 #

#calculates 17 new values, suming the last three values of the array, and adds the new accumalator value(s) to the array sequance
for i in range (0,17): 
    a = sequance[-1] + sequance[-2] +sequance[-3] 
    sequance.append(a) 

#prints the sequance
print(sequance)
```

```
#defines an array p with 
p = list(range(0,20))
plt.plot(l,p, "r.")

#sets a limit on the y axis
plt.ylim(0, 20)

#adds gridlines and labels to the graph
plt.grid()
plt.title("Number in the Sequance Versus Place in the Squance")
plt.xlabel("Number in Sequance")
plt.ylabel("Place in Sequance")

#Channges the intervilles on the graph (more ledgeible)
plt.xticks(list(range(0, 55000, 5000)))
plt.yticks(list(range(1,21)))
```

```
import numpy as np

u = 40 # initial velocity in m 
y = 50 # distance from origen in m
a = -9.81 # acceleration due to gravity m/s/s


t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101) # defines an array of 101 time values in the range from 0 to 10 seconds 
h = y + u * t + (a * t**2 / 2) #calculates hight of ball at each time values

plt.plot(t, h, "r", label = "y(t)") # plots t on x axis against h on y axix and changes the line colour to red

#adds limits to the graph
plt.xlim(0, 10) 
plt.ylim(0, 150)

# adds labels and gridlines
plt.title("Hight of a ball thrown verticially upwards from a cliff with respect to time")
plt.xlabel("time (s)")
plt.ylabel("hight from base of cliff (m)")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

Comment: Add a semi-colon `;` after the last statement if you don't want the `repr` of the result to be printed.

Comment: @Brian61354270 That's brilliant thanks a million. I saw on the link the "pass" statement and that seems to work great too!